# Implementing Isolation Forest in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to implement Isolation Forests algorithm using Spark Scala  Maven project. It is explained on this link:  [iforest example](https://github.com/titicaca/spark-iforest).

My question is: when I try to implement the suggested code I collect this error :
`object iforest is not a member of package org.apache.spark.ml`
I tried to `import org.apache.spark.ml` and changed the Spark-core dependency to vesrion 2.2.0 as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 4):

You can try [this Spark/Scala implementation of the isolation forest algorithm](https://github.com/linkedin/isolation-forest), which has artifacts available in the public Maven Central repository.

You can declare the dependency in your project's pom.xml as:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.linkedin.isolation-forest</groupId>
  <artifactId>isolation-forest_3.2.0_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Other available artifact versions are listed [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=com.linkedin.isolation-forest).

Answer (score 1):

This `spark-iforest` artifact is not included in official distribution nor present in any centralized artifact distribution resource, so to use it you need to build it on your own, either as a separate library or inside your project.

This library should not use package name of external sources at first place, because it made a false offer that it is available within Spark itself.

Comment: @FoaadMohamadHaddod if it answers your problem then please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it here and for your next questions on SO.